# Standardize values in a data-frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df which looks like:

```
id colour  response
 1   blue    curent 
 2    red   loaning
 3 yellow   current
 4  green      loan 
 5    red   currret
 6  green      loan
```

You can see the values in the response column are not uniform and I would like to get the to snap to a standardized set of responses.

I also have a validation list `validate` which looks like

```
validate
 current
    loan
transfer
```

I would like to standardise the response column in the df based on the first three characters in the entry against the validate list

So the eventual output would look like:

```
id colour  response
 1   blue   current
 2    red      loan
 3 yellow   current
 4  green      loan 
 5    red   current
 6  green      loan
```

have tried to use fnmatch

```
pattern = 'cur*'
fnmatch.filter(df, pattern) = 'current'
```

but can't change the values in the df.

If anyone could offer assistance it would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map`

```
In [3664]: mapping = dict(zip(s.str[:3], s))

In [3665]: df.response.str[:3].map(mapping)
Out[3665]:
0    current
1       loan
2    current
3       loan
4    current
5       loan
Name: response, dtype: object

In [3666]: df['response2'] = df.response.str[:3].map(mapping)

In [3667]: df
Out[3667]:
   id  colour response response2
0   1    blue   curent   current
1   2     red  loaning      loan
2   3  yellow  current   current
3   4   green     loan      loan
4   5     red  currret   current
5   6   green     loan      loan
```

Where `s` is series of validation values.

```
In [3650]: s
Out[3650]:
0     current
1        loan
2    transfer
Name: validate, dtype: object
```

---

Details

```
In [3652]: mapping
Out[3652]: {'cur': 'current', 'loa': 'loan', 'tra': 'transfer'}
```

`mapping` can be series too

```
In [3678]: pd.Series(s.str[:3].values, index=s.values)
Out[3678]:
current     cur
loan        loa
transfer    tra
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks that works for values that are in the validation dictionary.  If for some reason there is value in the response column that is not in the dictionary (say 'transfer'), is there a way to flag this? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy match ?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
a=[]
for x in df.response:
    a.append([process.extract(x, val.validate, limit=1)][0][0][0])
df['response2']=a
df
Out[867]: 
   id  colour response response2
0   1    blue   curent   current
1   2     red  loaning      loan
2   3  yellow  current   current
3   4   green     loan      loan
4   5     red  currret   current
5   6   green     loan      loan
```